# Turn Sticky Edges Off

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, 16.10

To prevent my graphics card from crashing after a few minutes, I had to add the following configuration:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option      "DRI"   "false"
EndSection
```

This is the only change I made. Since then, if I turn off sticky edges for my displays, they remain sticky, and the launcher bar appears on both monitors even though it is set to appear only on the left one.

Both settings (sticky edges off + launcher bar placement) worked before this little change.

How can I make it work again?

*It is very important to me, since I have fullscreen photos on the left screen and a photo list on the right, and I need to move the mouse pointer from one screen to the other quite often to put photos on the list. I can not use keys to move the photos because dragging them is the only way. Thus I need to turn off sticky edges again.*